# JsonSchema.Net stops validation at first property with inappropriate error

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema, json-everything

I have JSON schema generated using [JsonSchema.Net.Generation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Generation/3.0.3?_src=template). My classes for schema are as below:

```
class PaymentInitiationSchema
{
    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("actions")]
    public string[] Actions { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("locations")]
    public string[] Locations { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("instructedAmount")]
    public InstructedAmount InstructedAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("creditorName")]
    public string CreditorName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("creditorAccount")]
    public CreditorAccount CreditorAccount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("reemitanceInformationUnstructured")]
    public string ReemitanceInformationUnstructured { get; set; }
}

class InstructedAmount
{
    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

class CreditorAccount
{
    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("iban")]
    public string Iban { get; set; }
}
```

and it's the generated schema:

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "type":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "actions":{
         "$ref":"#/$defs/array"
      },
      "locations":{
         "$ref":"#/$defs/array"
      },
      "instructedAmount":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "currency":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "amount":{
               "type":"number"
            }
         },
         "required":[
            "currency",
            "amount"
         ]
      },
      "creditorName":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "creditorAccount":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "iban":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         },
         "required":[
            "iban"
         ]
      },
      "reemitanceInformationUnstructured":{
         "type":"string"
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "type",
      "actions",
      "locations",
      "instructedAmount",
      "creditorName",
      "creditorAccount",
      "reemitanceInformationUnstructured"
   ],
   "$defs":{
      "array":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "type":"string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I created sample function to validate given JSON:

```
static bool IsValid(string requestedAuthorizationDetails, JsonSchema authorizationDetailsSchema)
{
    try
    {
        JsonDocument.Parse(requestedAuthorizationDetails);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    var result = authorizationDetailsSchema.Validate(requestedAuthorizationDetails, new ValidationOptions
    {
        OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed
    });

    Console.WriteLine(result.Message + " at " + result.SchemaLocation.Source);

    return result.IsValid;
}
```

And it's always false for this call:

```
var schemaBuilder = new JsonSchemaBuilder();
var schema = schemaBuilder.FromType<PaymentInitiationSchema>().Build();

Console.WriteLine(IsValid(@"{
      ""type"": ""payment_initiation"",
      ""actions"": [
         ""initiate"",
         ""status"",
         ""cancel""
      ],
      ""locations"": [
         ""https://example.com/payments""
      ],
      ""instructedAmount"": {
         ""currency"": ""EUR"",
         ""amount"": 123.50
      },
      ""creditorName"": ""Merchant A"",
      ""creditorAccount"": {
         ""iban"": ""DE02100100109307118603""
      },
      ""remittanceInformationUnstructured"": ""Ref Number Merchant""
   }", schema));
```

And the error is also always the same:

> Value is "string" but should be "object" at #/type

Really don't understand why. I thought that maybe there is conflict between `type` at top of the JSON scheme and the `type` as required parameter. But even if I removed `type` from parameters the same error stills occurs.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of the libs you're using, but have you checked over at https://json-everything.net?

Inputting your generated schema and the instance you wrote, it says that two properties are the problems (I've edited the output down to just the errors for ease of viewing):

```json
{
  "valid": false,
  "evaluationPath": "",
  "schemaLocation": "https://json-everything.net/43e8b7754c",
  "instanceLocation": "",
  "errors": {
    "required": "Required properties [\"reemitanceInformationUnstructured\"] were not present"
  },
  "details": [
    {
      "valid": false,
      "evaluationPath": "/properties/creditorAccount",
      "schemaLocation": "https://json-everything.net/43e8b7754c#/properties/creditorAccount",
      "instanceLocation": "/creditorAccount",
      "errors": {
        "required": "Required properties [\"iban\"] were not present"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks like you have two typos.  Changing `remittanceInformationUnstructured` to `reemitanceInformationUnstructured` and `ban` to `iban` allows the data to validate.

Comment: Instead of passing the string to the `Validate` function, I started passing this string parsed to JsonDocument and everything works now. Any ideas why?

Comment: The `Validate()` method actually takes a `JsonNode`, and there's an implicit conversion from `string` to `JsonNode`.  So you were validating a string.  You can read the docs at https://json-everything.net/json-schema#evaluating-instances.  I'll try to add a note about the gotcha about strings.  It's tripped up several people.

Comment: Another note:  Those docs are for the 4.0 beta version.  For `Evaluate()` just use `Validate()` if you're using the 3.x version.